# Замена каждой буквы на следующую в алфавите

Tags: javascript, массивы

Я написала код, который меняет каждую введенную букву на следующую за ней в алфавите. Все работает, но мне решение не нравится, т.к. используется 2 раза подряд map. Можно ли сделать то же самое, но компактнее?

```js
const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
const changedValue = ['A', 'B', 'c', 'd']
const  lettersArr = letters.split('')

const res = changedValue.map(i => {
  let indexes = (lettersArr.findIndex((el) => el === i))+ 1
  return indexes
}).map(el => lettersArr[el])
console.log(res)
```

Comment: На что должна меняться буква `z`?

Comment: На первую в алфавите, это я пока не сделала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
const changedValue = ['A', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'z', '&']

const res = changedValue.map(i => {
  const index = letters.indexOf(i) + 1;
  return index ? letters[index % letters.length] : i;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Shoshanna Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const changedValue = ['A', 'B', 'c', 'd']
const res = changedValue.map(char => String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 1));
console.log(res);
```

Но помните, может быть проблема в букве `z`. На что она должна у вас меняться - только вам известно

Comment: Спасибо большое!  z буду менять на первую в алфавите, пока не дошла до этого